# Given the height b of a parallelogram, the horizontal side a, find the coordinates of the parallelogram?

Tags: geometry

The height of the parallelogram is given b, one adjacent side "a" (AB = a)is given.  I need to find the coordinates of C, D. the problem is described by the following images.
[image]

From my understanding, both y coordinates of D and C will be b because of the congruence and parallel properties. But how I will find x coordinates for both D and C? I tried considering the midpoint of the diagonals but didn't get anywhere. Please help.

Comment: Well D = (x,b), C=(x+a,b) but x can be any number you want.

Comment: You need at least *one* more piece of information.  the length of another side, an angle, the area, anything, but you do need something.

Comment: I understand your point. From y axis, you have considered that the distance to D is x, hence, D(x,b) and C(x+a,b). Hmm, I think that should be the case

Comment: The point is there is nothing in the diagram to determine what the $x$ coordinates could be.  Whatever we set $D$ and $C$ to we can just slide those by any distance and we still get a parallelagram satisfying all your conditions.

Comment: @fleablood well said, sir! Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

As fleablood points out [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378128/given-the-height-b-of-a-parallelogram-the-horizontal-side-a-find-the-coordinat#comment9149968_4378128), letting $x$ be any real number (positive, negative, or $0$), we can set $D=(x,b)$ and $C=(a+x,b),$ making $ABCD$ a parallelogram.